# Complex row sort in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sorting

For a market research project, I have a table in a sqlite database that specifies the exact position of a question. For different sets of respondents, questions might be asked or not asked, or asked in different positions. The position is indicated by consecutive numbers for each group.

The requirement is to sort this table in a way that the same questions are grouped if the order allows it. In other words: If group1 is asked q1, q2 and then q3, and group2 is asked q3 first, then the first three rows should be show for group1 followed by the first row for group2.

Table:

```
group | question | position
  g1  |     q1   |    1
  g1  |     q2   |    2
  g1  |     q3   |    3
  g1  |     q4   |    4
  g1  |     q5   |    5
  g1  |     q8   |    6
  g2  |     q2   |    1
  g2  |     q3   |    2
  g2  |     q7   |    3
  g2  |     q8   |    4
  g2  |     q1   |    5
```

How it should look like sorted:

```
group | question | position
  g1  |     q1   |    1
  g1  |     q2   |    2
  g2  |     q2   |    1
  g1  |     q3   |    3
  g2  |     q3   |    2
  g1  |     q4   |    4
  g1  |     q5   |    5
  g2  |     q7   |    3
  g1  |     q8   |    4
  g2  |     q8   |    6
  g2  |     q1   |    5
```

I tried all kinds of sorts and groups, but can't solve the problem. Since the database is accessed through python, I could perform the sorting there, but I have a strong preference to pull already sorted data.

Comment: The description is unclear. How do you determine the position of any single question? How would you determine that a question is sorted in the wrong position?

Comment: @CL The position is determined by the position column for each group individually. g1 would see q1 first, then q2,etc. g2 starts with q2 and ends with q1. Wrong sorting occurs in two scenarios: First, the orginal flow is not preserved, i.e. in the final table the numbers in position column must increase for each group. Second, the same questions need to be grouped if possible. The sorted table starts off with g1-q1, since it is the first question for g1, and q1 is not asked for g2. q2 is asked for both groups, and it is therefore grouped in row 2 and 3.

Comment: That information belongs in the question. And the second table is not correctly sorted according to your description.